# Can I use Hive Virtual Columns with Pig Latin HCatLoader

Tags: hive, apache-pig

I can use Hive virtual columns to uniquely identify a record 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns

Is there an equivalent way to do this with Pig Latin? Specifically, can I access these same virtual columns using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader? If not, is there another way to identify a unique pointer for each record that can be used to reference the same record each time? For example, if I have a table

**Student|Class|Grade**

Joe    |Math |A

Mary   |Math |A

Mike   |Bio  |B

and another table I generated with a unique key from virtual columns

**key                                          |column |value**

[input_file_name]+[block_offset_inside_file] | Student | Joe

then I could trace the key back to the original record with another Hive Query without explicitly creating another table that has this key appended as a column.

Can I do this with Pig Latin?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Should be pretty easy to figure it out.

Comment: I have tried but the virtual columns are not available in pig from what I can tell. I spent a good deal of time looking for any documentation or examples that would show this but came up with nothing so far. Since both hive and pig are using mapreduce, I would hope there would be some equivalent between them but it seems like that might not be the case in this situation. I was hoping that it was possible that there was a way to access the virtual columns of which I am not yet aware!